# Rotate PositionComponent around a fixed position(x,y) coordinate

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm trying to get a PositionComponent to rotate around a central fixed point in the game world, the anchors are all within the component itself so I'm a bit stumped.

Edit: Just for anyone else looking to do something similar managed to get it to work  with

```dart
void update(double dt){
 super.update(dt);
 double oldRadian = anchorComponent.angle;
 anchorComponent.angle += rotation * dt;
 anchorComponent.angle %= 2 * math.pi;
 double newRadian = anchorComponent.angle - oldRadian;
 rotatingComponent.angle = anchorComponent.angle;
 double x = rotatingComponent.position.x;
 double y = rotatingComponent.position.y;
 rotatingComponent.position.x = cos(newRadian) * (x - anchorComponent.position.x) - 
  sin(newRadian) * (y - anchorComponent.position.y) +
  anchorComponent.position.x;
 rotatingComponent.position.y = sin(newRadian) * (x - anchorComponent.position.x) +
  cos(newRadian) * (y - anchorComponent.position.y) +
  anchorComponent.position.y;
}
```

Now rotatingComponent rotates around anchorComponent (both positionComponents) when variable rotation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MoveAlongPathEffect` to make the component move in a circle around a point and then you can combine that with the `lookAt` method to make the component rotate "inwards" so that it looks like it is rotating around the point. You might have to set `nativeAngle` too, depending on how the `PositionComponent` that you want to rotate looks like.